# What should my controls look like?

Tags: controls, user-experience, powerbuilder

I'm migrating an application from PowerBuilder 9 to PowerBuilder 12 Classic. In the course of this, I've noticed that PB now renders some of the controls differently: for example, on one window, some of the dropdown data windows are marked to render with a box around them, while others aren't -- but they all render with the box. PB12 fixes this, rendering each control as actually specified.

So, as long as I'm going through here and making things consistent, I might as well make *everything* consistent, as far as possible. We'll be deploying this on Windows 7 machines for the next couple of years, at least, so Aero is the theme I want to aim for, either with the PB defaults or by setting the controls to look like they should. I tried looking at the MS UX guidelines, but either I didn't find the right page, or it doesn't actually say. So, what should the controls look like? Boxes? Lowered? NoBorder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Much has to do with the user theme as well as the icon size they have chosen to use on their desktops.  One thing to make sure of, however, is that you do not have the 'Windows classic style' option checked on the project from which you build your executable.

Comment: Actually, that was a useful comment for the reverse reason - I ended up turning classic style on for the sake of having it continue to look the same and not confuse the users. :-)